# MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: Invalid transaction value of 0.001 number must be in wei

Tags: web3js, metamask

I want use MetaMask to send ETH or ERC20 Tokens
The following script i am using is throwing error,

> RPC Error: Error: Invalid transaction value of 0.001 number must be
>   in wei

```
const method = 'eth_sendTransaction'
const parameters = [{
    from: account,
    to: to,
    value: 0.001
}]
const from = account
const payload = {
    method: method,
    params: parameters,
    from: from,
}
web3.currentProvider.sendAsync(payload, function (err, response) {

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ether, the smallest unit of the currency is wei, and 1 ETH === 10^18 wei

```
var weiValue = web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether'); // 1 ether 
console.log(weiValue);//1000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

MetaMask no longer injects web3. For details, see: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#replacing-window-web3